# How can a user see all the email address aliases for their Exchange account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, outlook-web-access

My institution has several domains, and I know that multiple email addresses are configured to be routed to my one Exchange account. I know that I have seen this list in GUI once, and I believe it was in Outlook or Outlook Web Access. I cannot seem to find that information any more - where is it?

Currently, I am using Outlook 2016 and OWA 2013.

Answer (score 2):

In Outlook 2016, select the "Home" tab, choose "Address Book", search for any user, double-click the user, click the "E-mail Addresses" tab.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to see it from Powershell.

```
Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

$credential = Get-Credential YourIdentity@company.com

Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $credential

Get-Recipient -Identity "Name Lastname" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses
```

Comment: Great idea. Doesn't work with 2FA, though: "Error Acquiring Token: External security challenge not satisfied. User will be redirected to another page or authentication provider to satisfy additional authentication challenges."